# Absolute position element centered as long as it fits on the screen

Tags: css

I am creating a tooltip system using only CSS that displays tooltips absolute centered below the element you can hover over to see the tooltip. Tooltips must have a minimum width. In my example below, you will see this works fine on the second element. On the first though, the tooltip does not fit on the screen and will be cut off. In this scenario (the tooltip not fitting on screen on the left side) it should just left align. If it were on the right side of the screen, it should align right. I might be pushing the CSS boundaries, but might there be a CSS solution?

**Edit:** as others have pointed out, this cannot be done purely in CSS. JavaScript can be used with [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). Of course, there are also pre-made solutions such as [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org/).

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px;
}

[data-tooltip]::after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 2em auto;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: darkgray;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px silver;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 10px 0px">
  <span data-tooltip="This text (or element) will be cut off somewhat on the left side">Hover me
  </span>
  <span data-tooltip="This tooltip will be completely shown because it is not near any edge">Second one
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this control impossible with only css. you need to use javascript.

Comment: It's possible if you do something like https://jsfiddle.net/bwjm96vc/. You need to vertically split the screen/page, optimally using flexbox and then target the first-child of the left side, and last-child of the right. If that's applicable...

Comment: @VXp, I applaud your suggestion. This would be a great solution if I had the liberty to build pages like this. Unfortunately, I will have to find a solution so that the elements can be used anywhere on the page regardless of a parent container. So I guess JS is the way to go...

Comment: Ty, thought so. :) I'm afraid you're right.